# How to call/set a custom input method?

Tags: android, methods, input, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I followed these tutorial of developer.android, "Creating an Input Method" and "SoftKeyboard - Soft Keyboard sample".

Think it`s everything correct, but the custom keyboard dont pop up, what i`m doing wrong?

Only the default keyboard shows up.

Answer (score 0):

The user has to choose that input method editor, either from the Settings app (for a permanent change) or via the little keyboard icon you typically see in the lower-left corner of every input method editor.